# Are there non trivial two-party stabilizers in bipartite entanglement for product states?

Tags: entanglement, stabilizer-state

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.06437) recent paper where the authors discuss finite classification of entanglement types, on pg. 29 in appendix A, it is claimed that in bipartite entanglement for product state $|00\rangle$ there are no non-trivial two-party [stabilizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Fixed_points_and_stabilizer_subgroups). Here, stabilizer is defined as the group of local unitary actions which keep the pure state invariant up to a global phase. However for a generic state $\psi=a|00\rangle+b|11\rangle$ with $a>0,b>0$ it is claimed that there exists such a non-trivial two-party stabilizer given by $$u_A \otimes u_B=e^{i \theta}\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i \alpha_1} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i \alpha_2}\end{array}\right) \otimes\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{-i \alpha_1} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i \alpha_2}\end{array}\right)$$

I don't understand why this is not a valid two-party stabilizer for $|00\rangle$ i.e. why is the condition $a>0,b>0$ necessary for writing the above equation? Maybe a proper derivation of the above equation will provide the answer which the paper does not provide (A similar derivation can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0001091), but that doesn't exactly answer my question). However, the above is intuitively obvious because the authors are *defining* entanglement to be local unitary actions on the subsystems such that one such action cancels off the other, quantifying the "spooky action at a distance". So basically we operate two phase shift gates along with a global $U(1)$ phase  $e^{i\theta}$ infront.

To inspect my doubt, I also tried acting on $|00\rangle=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ with $$u_A\otimes u_B=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 e^{i \theta } & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & e^{i \text{$\alpha $1}-i \text{$\alpha $2}+i \theta } & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & e^{-i \text{$\alpha $1}+i \text{$\alpha $2}+i \theta } & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i \theta } \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which clearly stabilizes $|00\rangle$ apart from the phase $e^{i\theta}$.

Alternatively, following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434875/) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0001091) I also tried writing the state $|00\rangle$ in Schmidt-form as
$$|00\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=T~~(\text{let})$$ and doing $u_A T u_B^T$ which yielded the same result i.e. $e^{i\theta}T$.(Although I don't understand exactly why there should we act by *transpose* of $u_B$ from the right and not $u_B^{-1}=u_B^{\dagger}$)

I have been doing something terribly wrong in both of these calculations because if truly there was a non-trivial two-party stabilizer for a product state then it would mean (falsely) that a product state is entangled(because then it's entanglement group would be non-trivial(=$U(1)$) as shown in the paper's calculation for the generic state). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It will be very helpful if someone adds relevant tags as I am new to this site.

Comment: This is indeed strange. The answer must come down to why something is defined as "trivial" (something like "if the state is only multiplied by $\exp(i \theta)$ and doesn't depend on $\alpha_1$ or $\alpha_2$ then it's trivial) but I'm not sure